# Syntax error expecting identifier in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I was just checking functionality of opencart's cart controller. Where i saw

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);
                    $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
                }
            }
```

Its working fine. But when i change it to

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
                if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
                    $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);
                    $this->'model_total_' . $result['code']->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
                    }
            }
```

its giving me an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''model_total_''`. I don't know why this happened. Does it refer to same or not. If not then why i have to use curly braces `$this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}` for it. Can anyone explain.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I believe wrapping it in the `{}` identifies it as a variable, when you removed them, you made php interpret it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not accepting the concatenation of your result there, so try this,

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
     if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
         $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);
         $code = 'model_total_' . $result['code'];
         $this->$code->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
     }
}
```

or

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
     if ($this->config->get($result['code'] . '_status')) {
         $this->load->model('total/' . $result['code']);
         $this->{'model_total_' . $result['code']}->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes); // wrap with {}
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

Wrapping with `{}` is required when you are using array element for concatenation.

```
$this->'model_total_' . $result['code']->getTotal($total_data, $total, $taxes);
                        ^             ^
```

you are using array element for concatenation, So you are getting error.

You can even notice that my first example works without `{}`, because its normal variable.

Comment: How is your second block different from what OP says works?

Comment: Yes its working. But why to use `$this->{----}` braces

Comment: When your using array element you should use races. If its a simple variable you will not get any error if you dont use braces.

Comment: @VedPandya Check my edited answer. I think that is clear why you should use `{}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an expression as a property name, you have to put it in `{}` unless it's just a single variable.